# Difference between full text search in stored procedure and full text search as query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to use full text search in a stored procedure but I don't know why the result when searching in stored procedure is so different than when execute it as query.

This is the query :

```
SELECT 
       ItemRevisions.ItemId, ItemRevisions.NameSearch, 
       ItemRevisions.Phone, ItemRevisions.RevisionStateId 
    FROM
       ItemRevisions
    WHERE 
       ItemRevisions.CategoryId = '198' 
       AND CONTAINS(ItemRevisions.*, 'Viện')
```

This is the stored produce uses this query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetListPlaceByCategory]
    @categoryID int,
    @searchstring varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      ItemRevisions.ItemId,
      ItemRevisions.NameSearch,
      ItemRevisions.Phone,
      ItemRevisions.RevisionStateId 
   FROM 
      ItemRevisions
   WHERE 
      ItemRevisions.CategoryId = @categoryID 
      AND CONTAINS(ItemRevisions.*,@searchstring)
END
```

and the input of stored produce is : `198 , "Viện"`

The result of query is `18` but the stored procedure is `3`.

Comment: First of all - your query uses `DISTINCT` and your stored procedures does **not** use that; also: your query uses `FREETEXT` while your procedures uses `CONTAINS` --> they're **not** the same!

Comment: Marc_s is right, contains will give a much more limited set of results than freetext will as freetext will look for inflectional forms of words, whereas contains will not (by default).

Comment: Sorry all. I edited the question and the result is the same. @@

Comment: Your query has `'198'` as a string, the stored procedure has it as an integer. Assuming `CategoryId` is a string, this may give different results and even cause an exception. Also the procedure accepts `varchar(200)` whereas you probably want `nvarchar(200)` given your accented characters.